# Preposition "to" with places in present perfect

Tags: grammar, prepositions, american-english, present-perfect

in BrE it is normal to say e.g.:

"*She's been **to** Africa twice.*"

In the past simple, the preposition would be "in":

"*She was **in** Africa twice.*"

**Question 1**: Why is there such a difference?

**Question 2**: Does **American** English use the preposition "to" with places in present perfect, too?

**Question 3**: What changes if I say "*I've been **in** Africa twice.*" instead?

Thanks!

Comment: The confusion stems from the fact that *been* is the past participle of two verbs - *be* and *go*. *Go* collocates with *to*, whereas *be* collocates with *in*. When you say you are changing tenses, you are actually changing verbs - that is why the preposition changes.

Comment: It might be clearer if I give some examples - *she's been to Africa twice* would become *she went to Africa twice* in the past simple. Here the verb is *go*. *She was in Africa for some time* would become *she has been in Africa for some time* in the present perfect. Here the verb is *be*.

Comment: @Minty -- thanks a lot! That makes sense. Any idea if that is only a British thing? I would assume in AmE, the past participle of "go" is "gone", and never "been".

Comment: Americans talk funny, but not that funny.

Comment: BTW it might be more accurate to say that the true past participle of *go* is *gone*, but that it can also borrow the past participle of *be*. Practically speaking it amounts to the same thing, and I think it's easier to think of *go* as having two past participles.

Comment: We (AmE) use both.  “gone” emphasizes the trip, “been” emphasizes the destination.

Comment: @Minty Your comment that _been_ is the PP of both _be_ and _go_ pricked up my ears. Could you possibly provide a reference to support that as it would be very helpful for me here to explain the usage to non-native speakers. (I can't believe how many of this type of Q we get every month.)

Comment: @Cascabel Long story (and I am definitely not an EFL teacher) but I saw it explained that way in a TEFL textbook for elementary students. It had a red cover and may have been called Cutting Edge.

Comment: @Cascabel กรุงเทพมหานคร, but I think it was just a note - probably no more detailed than the discussion in these comments.

Comment: @Jim  I assume that by "We (AmE) use both" you mean "both gone and been". But what about the preposition "to" with present perfect? Is it common, or is "in" more common? That was my Question 2.

Comment: Sorry @Minty I'm coming up with a bunch of _nada_ burgers on that title and geography. Maybe it was only published locally for a private academy in Thailand.

Comment: I wonder why this question was downvoted? Is there any meta-moderation or feedback on voting?

Answer (score 2):

We have to be careful about how we use the term *past tense*.  The verb *go* has no cognate past **simple** form derived from it.  It has a kind of past participle *gone*.  So if we want a past simple, meaning the past of what *I go* means, we have to resort to the past of another word, now rare in ordinary (non-poetical or archaic) language:  'wend', whose past form is 'went'.

But the use of 'been' in the way that puzzles you goes back a long way.  There is the nursery rhyme, for example:-

> Pussy cat, pussy cat, where have you been?
>
> I've been to London to look at the Queen.

"I have been to London" is in the poem, not "I have been in London."  It means almost the same as "I have been in London", but not quite the same, I should say.  It has the sense of going to a place and coming back again **in a short time**.

So "I've been to Africa twice" means that I have **visited** Africa twice (perhaps on holiday, or business or for research).  "I've been **in** Africa twice", on the other hand could mean the same thing, but it could equally means that I have lived in Africa for some significant period of time (longer than a long holiday, for example).